# Stuck on practice questions for while loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm doing some practice questions for a upcoming test and can't seem to wrap my head around while loops at the moment.

The code I've had to write was relatively simple it's the interpretation however I am struggling with:

```
row = 1
count = 0
end = 6
while row < end:
    count = count + row
    print(count)
    row = row + 1 
print('The End')
```

I am trying to answer the following questions:

1. What is the output of the program? (I realise I can run the code, but the practice question wants me to interpret without doing so, and I don't know how to interpret it).
2. How many times is the body of the loop executed?
3. How many times is the condition row < end checked?
4. What is the value of the variable row when the while loop finishes?

Please understand I am not cheating as this is merely practice for an upcoming test. I am a novice at Python and am struggling a bit when it comes to concepts like these. Therefore if you could answer those questions with some minor explanations I'm pretty sure I'll understand the gist of it.

Thanks for all your help, it truly is appreciated.

Comment: I was going to fix your indentation, but realized you haven't even put in line breaks in the relevant places. Please fix that.

Comment: @cchu I have adjusted the formatting of your code for readability. If this does *not* reflect the indentation of your code, please adjust it so it exactly matches.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what I've done wrong Daniel? As such, I can't really fix anything which is why I am here for help in the first place.

Comment: I would recommend reading up on [how to step through a program by hand](http://m.wikihow.com/Hand-Trace-Through-Software-Code). Once you've got a grasp on that, the rest should be much easier.

Comment: @Cyber, thank you Cyber. Your help with that is appreciated. If you'd be willing to continue your help, would you be generous enough to help me with the interpretation side of the code?

Comment: @DanielRoseman's point is that in python, whitespace and indentation are *part of the syntax*. Removing a newline or indenting/unindenting changes the meaning of your code. It's always important to reproduce python *exactly*

Comment: @aruisdante, I understand what you mean, but I've read through my textbook that I own and tried to learn from some online sources but overall I just don't understand while loops very well, as such I can't answer the interpretation questions.

Comment: The concept of understanding a `while` loop is completely separate from understanding how to hand-interpret a simple program. If you know how to do the latter, it should lead you directly to what you don't understand about the former (there will be a 'blank' where you don't understand what should happen). You can then guide yourself to better understand the bits you're missing until your hand-evaluation matches the output from actually running the program.

Comment: Use [this website](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) to visualize your program's execution.

Comment: To put it another way, we could explain how `while` loops work (do whatever is inside the scope of the `while` block as long as `condition` continues to be `True`. The condition is checked before entering the block the first time, and every time the loop repeats), but that's just going to be the same thing that's in your textbook/tutorials. Until you start stepping through the program, you won't understand *why* you don't understand the `while` loop.

Comment: @MackM, thank you very much. That really helped me understand the processes that take place.

Comment: @aruisdante, thank you as well for your insight, it is very useful. If you don't mind, would you double check the answers I got?

Comment: @cchu I am glad that helped you.  Welcome to StackOverflow, the help center has a nice guide [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on how to ask questions that will get better, faster answers.

Comment: @MackM, I appreciate the help.

Also if you don't mind, would you be willing to just quickly double check my answers?

Comment: Q5) the output of the program would be:
1
3
6
10
15
The End

Q6) Five times.
Q7) Five times.
Q8) Six

Comment: You are correct on all except Q3 in your question.  Every time the line is visited in the visualizer I linked to, it is executed.

Comment: @MackM, oh I see. I guess I missed one, the answer should be six then? Is that right?

Comment: Glad it helped. I hope you don't think I was trying to be harsh, it's just that it's an important skill to understand that begin able to step through a program by hand is different from understanding what every line in the code does :) Hand-stepping is a very valuable debugging tool, because it will quickly guide you to areas where you don't understand what/why the code is doing what it is doing, and that's general where the bug (either with you code, or your understanding of what the code is supposed to do) is.

Comment: @aruisdante, not at all. I appreciate the straightforwardness while still actually attempting to help my situation unlike Daniel sadly. I will have to return to the sites you provided me at a later time as I have been studying literally all through the night. But from what I read, if I could master those manual skills it'll really help me overall.

Thanks again for your valued input.

Answer (score 2):

Let's go over this line by line, the way you manually trace code is the same for any situation.

```
[1] row = 1
[2] count = 0
[3] end = 6
```

In line 1,2,3 variables are created with an initial value. `row` will have a value of 1, `count` will have a value of 0, and `end` will have a value of 6

```
[7] while row < end:
[8]    count = count + row
[9]    print(count)
[10]   row = row + 1
```

Now we start the loop. To begin, python checks if `row` is less than `6`. From lines [1]-[3], we know `row=1` and `end=6`. Is 1 less than 6? Yes. So Python will go to line [8] now.

In line [8], the variable `count` is assigned a new value of `count+row`. In other words, we are just adding `row` to `count`. `count` was 0, and row is 1, so `count` now is 0+1, or 1.

In line [9] we print the current value of `count`, which is now 1.

In line [10], `row` becomes `row+1`, we are just incrementing the value of `row` by 1. `row` was 1, now it is 2.

After line [10], the body of the loop ends, so we go back to line [7], the beginning of the loop.

Lets check if `row` is less than `end`. `end` is 6, but `row` is now 2, because we incremented it on line [10]. 2<6 still, so we go through the loop again.

On line [8], we do what we did before, add `row` to `count`. `row` is 2, and `count` is 1. So the new value of `count` is 3.

On line [9], we print the value of `count` again, which is 3.

We're at line [10] again, `row` was 2, now it will be 3. After this we go back to line [7]. Every time we finish the loop body, we go back to line [7] and check if `row` is less than `end`. Once `row` is no longer less than ``end`, the loop terminates, and line [11] is called

`[11] print('The End')`

This prints out a string that says `The End`

I'm not going to give the specific answers to your question, as it's important you understand this yourself. Start with what I gave you and continue the manual trace yourself. I'm more than happy to tell you if you're right or wrong, but you should put an effort into solving it yourself :) , StackOverflow is available when you're doing homework, but you can't log on and ask questions during a test or exam - so you should study this well!

Answer (score 0):

Given this code:

```
row = 1
count = 0
end = 6
while row < end:
    count = count + row
    print(count)
    row = row + 1 
print 'end'
```

What is the output of the program?

```
1
3
6
10
15
end
```

How many times is the body of the loop executed? **5**

How many times is the condition row < end checked? **6**

What is the value of the variable `row` when the while loop finishes? **15**

Now let's step through the code:

```
row, count, end = 1, 0 6
```

First check at while loop:

```
row = 1
end = 6
row < end is True
```

Enter while loop for 1st time:

```
count = 0 + 1
row = 1 + 1
```

2nd check at while loop:

```
row = 2
end = 6
row < end is True
```

Enter while loop 2nd time:

```
count = 1 + 2
row = 2 + 1
```

3rd check at while loop:

```
row = 3
end = 6
row < end is True
```

Enter while loop 3rd time:

```
count = 3 + 3
row = 3 + 1
```

4th check at while loop:

```
row = 4
end = 6
row < end is True
```

Enter while loop 4th time

```
count = 6 + 4
row = 4 + 1
```

5th check at while loop:

```
row = 5
end = 6
row < end is True
```

Enter while loop 5th time

```
count = 10 + 5
row = 5 + 1
```

6th check at while loop:

```
row = 6
end = 6
row < end is Fale
```

Breaks while condition and

```
print 'end'
```